# how to get Multiple lines of text values from a document library in sharepoint 2013 using client object model

Tags: csom

how to get Multiple lines of text values from a document library in sharepoint 2013 using client object model

I tried this code to get value :

```
        docEnumerator = collVideoLibrary.getEnumerator();
        //Looping through the collection
        while (docEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            docItem = docEnumerator.get_current();
            var description = docItem.get_item('Description');
```

but I didn't get the Description form document library

please do needful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Description0` as column's internal name because SharePoint Document Library already contains a column named as `Description` and if you try to create another custom column whose **DisplayName** is **Description** then its **InternalName** would be `Description0`